# API Error Code: 191 for Share Dialog in facebook UI

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

API Error Code: 191 for Share Dialog in facebook UI

I've been trying to make the FB.ui to work. Unforunately, I keep getting an error:

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

If I go to my App basic info in https://developers.facebook.com/

I don't see any problem, everything looks fine:

```
App ID: 471513259597047
Display Name: Calculator
Site URL: http://www.calculator.com
```

I filled everything needed, yet I am still getting the 191 error. I am testing this in localhost by the way.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>My Feed Dialog Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
    <p id='msg'></p>

    <script> 
      FB.init({appId: "471513259597047", status: true, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          redirect_uri: 'http://www.calculator.com',
          link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
          picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
          name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
          caption: 'Reference Documentation',
          description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with people.'
        };

        function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“I am testing this in localhost by the way”_ – then set a localhost URL in your app settings as well (and don’t set a redirect_uri explicitly, as it is not necessary in most cases when working with the SDKs).

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is some mismatch between the URL you specified while creating facebook app on developers.facebook.com and the URL specified in your code, Cross Check it.